# Ruby on Rails Triggers Update on Serialized Attribute Every Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple user model with a name and settings. After every save of user AREL is performing an update to the settings column. For example:

```
user = User.find_by_name('kevin')
user.save

(0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "updated_at" = '2011-10-20 19:58:06.363541', "settings" = '--- {}' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

None of the other fields are updated when calling save. Is this expected behavior? Why is it performing the update? Can it be turned off to not change if the serialized contents haven't changed? I've uploaded the sample project used to create a minimum case:

http://cl.ly/0p0j3Z3Y0L1x1I1p3Z0g

Comment: What is the output of `user.changes` if you call it immediately after the first line above? What if you specify a class for the attribute, e.g. `serialize :settings, Hash`?

Comment: @Jordan specifying a `Hash` does not help. `User.changes` returns an empty hash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior. It is very difficult to detect changes within a serialized attribute, so they are updated on every save.

Consider the following (ruby 1.8.7) irb session:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :001 > x = "--- \n:b: 2\n:a: 1\n"
 => "--- \n:b: 2\n:a: 1\n" 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :002 > y = "--- \n:a: 1\n:b: 2\n"
 => "--- \n:a: 1\n:b: 2\n" 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :003 > x == y
 => false 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :004 > YAML.load(x) == YAML.load(y)
 => true
```

Comment: Why? Couldn't a string comparison of the u.settings_was with the u.settings be made after being serialized?

Comment: .. updated the answer. Additionally, the Dirty module expects ActiveRecord to call a specific method when an attribute is changed, so that it gets notified about the change. For example, it would be very difficult to hook into the process of changing a hash value inplace.